# Как импортировать переменную из одного файла в другой?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть переменная в коде 1

public int health1;

Как ее импортировать в код 2, чтобы там можно было отнимать от него числа и т.д.?
И после этого, чтобы все изменения переменной применялись на код 1.

Comment: Поставил минус, эта тема поднималась десятки раз, да и ответ - первая ссылка в гугле, было бы желание...

Comment: Я искал, там фигня какая-то, хотя вопрос впринципе должен быть частым

Comment: [Первая ссылка в гугле](https://answers.unity.com/questions/42843/referencing-non-static-variables-from-another-scri.html), да и тут 100 раз задавали этот вопрос, повторюсь, было бы желание.

Comment: @ЯрославСмирнов, а почему убрали галочку с ответа спустя столько времени после того как приняли его?

Comment: @trollingchar очень непонятно и неудобно, да и сам способ я не проверял. Через  `private Script s1;`  и  `void Start()
    {
        s1 = GetComponent<Script1>(); }`  `s1.number = 1;` работает лучше

Comment: @ЯрославСмирнов Вы можете тогда оформить ответ на свой собственный вопрос и отметить его как правильный. Подробнее об этом: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой способ (**но не всегда самый правильный с точки зрения архитектуры**) - сделать ее статической:

```
public static int health1;
```

Статические переменные хранятся не в экземплярах класса, а существуют в единственном экземпляре. И обращаться к ним надо через имя самого класса, например

```
public class Tile {
    public static int size;
}
...
// где-то в другом классе:
int size = Tile.size;
```

Пример не самый удачный, потому что обычно размер тайла константный, но я показываю как использовать статические переменные.

Если поменять значение такой переменной в одном скрипте, а потом прочитать в другом, то оно изменится, потому что она одна на всю игру, общая для всех.

Вводить такого рода глобальные переменные нужно очень осторожно, а то их станет слишком много и можно легко запутаться где что лежит. Надо так проектировать архитектуру, чтобы например при взаимодействии двух объектов они передавались бы параметрами в функцию, тогда можно будет получить данные с них непосредственно. У меня например глобально хранятся обычно игровой мир, который всегда один, и интерфейс, который тоже один.

В общем, если объект (или переменная) будет точно один на всю игру, то этот вариант годится.

Если же здоровье будет у каждого юнита, то нужно оставить все как есть, а обрабатывать экземпляры классов. Например, объекты столкнулись и вызывается `OnCollisionEnter`:

```
public class Unit : MonoBehaviour {
    public int health; // не static
}
...
// где-то в другом классе:
private void OnCollisionEnter (Collision c) {
    var unit = c.gameObject.GetComponent <Unit> ();
    // все, мы получили класс, где хранится здоровье, делаем с ним что хотим
    unit.health = 0;
}
```